# MySQL Distinct Poor performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, distinct

I have a Distinct Select statement with multiple left joins that is performing poorly when my where clause is large.  Below is my statement

```
SELECT  DISTINCT u.*, ri.id as reg_id, d.id as dist_id
    FROM  users u
    LEFT JOIN  earned_points ep ON u.id = ep.user_id
    LEFT JOIN  distributors d ON d.id = ep.distributor_id
      OR  d.id = u.distributor_id
      OR  d.id = u.additional_distributor_id
    LEFT JOIN  registration_items_users riu ON u.id = riu.user_id
      AND  riu.distributor_id = d.id
      AND  riu.registration_item_id = 21
    LEFT JOIN  registration_items ri ON riu.registration_item_id = ri.id
    WHERE  d.id IN (201,281,321,631,901,971,1211,1601,1611,1621,
               1631,1641,1651,1661,1671,1681,1691,1701,1711,1721,1731,
               1741,1751,1761,1771,1781,2281,2291,2401,2781,2801,2931 );
```

The Explain for this query is below:
[image: select_explain]

This query take around 4 seconds to complete.  If I reduce the where down to one id then it speeds up to about 170ms.

Would appreciate any suggestion on how to make this query quicker.

Thank you

**Edit**

I was able to come up with a solution based on Rick James(accepted answer) suggestion.  using Union and getting rid of the Left Joins and Distinct did the trick.  This new query take around 200ms compared to the 4 second version above.

```
(SELECT  u.*, 
   (SELECT riu.registration_item_id 
       FROM registration_items_users riu 
       WHERE riu.user_id = u.id 
           AND riu.distributor_id = d.id 
           AND riu.registration_item_id = 21) as reg_id,
   d.id as dist_id
   FROM users u
   JOIN earned_points ep ON u.id = ep.user_id
   JOIN distributors d ON d.id = ep.distributor_id
       WHERE d.id IN (201,281,321,631,901,971,1211,1601,1611,1621,
            1631,1641,1651,1661,1671,1681,1691,1701,1711,1721,1731,
            1741,1751,1761,1771,1781,2281,2291,2401,2781,2801,2931))
   UNION
(SELECT  u.*, 
   (SELECT riu.registration_item_id 
       FROM registration_items_users riu 
       WHERE riu.user_id = u.id 
           AND riu.distributor_id = d.id 
           AND riu.registration_item_id = 21) as reg_id,
   d.id as dist_id
   FROM users u
   JOIN distributors d ON d.id = u.distributor_id
       WHERE d.id IN (201,281,321,631,901,971,1211,1601,1611,1621,
            1631,1641,1651,1661,1671,1681,1691,1701,1711,1721,1731,
            1741,1751,1761,1771,1781,2281,2291,2401,2781,2801,2931))
   UNION
(SELECT  u.*, 
   (SELECT riu.registration_item_id 
       FROM registration_items_users riu 
       WHERE riu.user_id = u.id 
           AND riu.distributor_id = d.id 
           AND riu.registration_item_id = 21) as reg_id,
   d.id as dist_id
   FROM users u
   JOIN distributors d ON d.id = u.additional_distributor_id
       WHERE d.id IN (201,281,321,631,901,971,1211,1601,1611,1621,
            1631,1641,1651,1661,1671,1681,1691,1701,1711,1721,1731,
            1741,1751,1761,1771,1781,2281,2291,2401,2781,2801,2931))
```

Comment: Isn't that to be expected? You have 32 ids in the list. 32 * 170 ms = 5440 ms. So it's performing slightly faster than linear. That being said, the IN() operator can be slow. You can try dumping the list of ids into a temp table and joining to that and creating indexes on your tables.

Comment: Yeah what I'm looking for is a non linear way to do this.  I haven't done temp tables before.  Could you point me in the right direction?  Thanks

Comment: I would try the indexes first, they can make the temp table moot

Comment: I feel I already have the indexes need on all the table.  Do you have any suggestions on something I'm missing?

Comment: What indexes do you have? You should look at the execution plan to get hints on which indexes you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `EXPLAIN`, look at the `u` line.  It is doing a "table scan" of about 6974 rows.

Get rid of `LEFT` unless the "right" table is optional.

Turn the `OR` into a `UNION`; that is where the indexes are failing you.  (`UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION DISTINCT`; pick whichever one make sense.)

Assuming the `LEFTs` can be removed, and assuming the `DISTINCT` can be moved from `SELECT` to `UNION`:

```
SELECT  u.*, ri.id as reg_id, d.id as dist_id
    FROM  users u
    JOIN  earned_points ep ON u.id = ep.user_id  -- ep needed only for this
    JOIN  distributors d ON d.id = ep.distributor_id  -- This one line differs
    JOIN  registration_items_users riu ON u.id = riu.user_id
      AND  riu.distributor_id = d.id
      AND  riu.registration_item_id = 21
    JOIN  registration_items ri ON riu.registration_item_id = ri.id
    WHERE  d.id IN (201,281,321,631,901,971,1211,1601,1611,1621,
                1631,1641,1651,1661,1671,1681,1691,1701,1711,1721,1731,
                1741,1751,1761,1771,1781,2281,2291,2401,2781,2801,2931 
                   )
    UNION  DISTINCT 
SELECT  u.*, ri.id as reg_id, d.id as dist_id
    FROM  users u
    JOIN  distributors d ON d.id = u.distributor_id
    JOIN  registration_items_users riu ON u.id = riu.user_id
      AND  riu.distributor_id = d.id
      AND  riu.registration_item_id = 21
    JOIN  registration_items ri ON riu.registration_item_id = ri.id
    WHERE  d.id IN (201,281,321,631,901,971,1211,1601,1611,1621,
                1631,1641,1651,1661,1671,1681,1691,1701,1711,1721,1731,
                1741,1751,1761,1771,1781,2281,2291,2401,2781,2801,2931 
                   )
    UNION  DISTINCT 
SELECT  u.*, ri.id as reg_id, d.id as dist_id
    FROM  users u
    JOIN  distributors d ON d.id = u.additional_distributor_id
    JOIN  registration_items_users riu ON u.id = riu.user_id
      AND  riu.distributor_id = d.id
      AND  riu.registration_item_id = 21
    JOIN  registration_items ri ON riu.registration_item_id = ri.id
    WHERE  d.id IN (201,281,321,631,901,971,1211,1601,1611,1621,
                1631,1641,1651,1661,1671,1681,1691,1701,1711,1721,1731,
                1741,1751,1761,1771,1781,2281,2291,2401,2781,2801,2931 
                   ) ;
```

It is generally a bad idea to splay an array across columns.  That seems to be what is going on with `distributors`.  And this mess may be a result of such.

**Edit**

Even better would be to pull the `ri` and `rui` stuff out of the selects and turn it into a subquery.  Here's the gist; I don't have the energy to write it all:

```
SELECT x.*,
        ( SELECT ... ri and rui stuff ... ) AS reg_id
    FROM (
        --  from above, less the ri and rui stuff:
        SELECT ...
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT ...
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT ...
         ) AS x;
```

Comment: This is great stuff!  The left joins are required sadly.  I'm going to take what you suggested and see when I come up with.  I'll let you know how it turns out.  Thank you.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction.  I was able to take what you said and come up with a query that is much faster.  I was able to remove all left joins and Distinct.  I'll update my question with my query and mark you answer as the accepted solution.  Thank you.